# shutil.copyfile does not copy all lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

77 lines are missing from my temporary output file `cloneTemp.txt`, when using `shutil.copyfile()`.
 Why is this?

**This file contains two functions. The first function creates a temporary file which will contain the data generated from a file called `newFileLocation` created by my** `Main.py`

```
import os
import sys
import shutil


    def cloneTemp(newFileLocation):
        cloneFile = open('cloneTemp.txt', 'w+')
        shutil.copyfile(newFileLocation, 'cloneTemp.txt')
```

**This second function will then send new lines to the beginning of `cloneTemp.txt`, copy the data from the newFileLocation to cloneTemp.txt and finally, write at the end of the cloneTemp.txt:**

```
def gridEnable(newFileLocation):

    if(x < 200):
        print x
        cloneTemp.write(x)
    else:
        cloneTemp.write(y)

    shutil.copyfile('cloneTemp.txt', newFileLocation)
```

Yet, lines are missing when it's copied over. Why is `newFileLocation` not being copied in it's entirety?

**EDIT**

`newFileLocation` is a file containing the output from `Main.py`, that is all. Since I can't prepend to the beginning of the `newFileLocation`, I am creating a temporary file of `newFileLocation` called `cloneTemp.txt` to copy over the data **only after** I've added the lines into the empty `cloneTemp.txt` that I require. After the lines are added, `shutil.copyfile()` should copy `newFileLocation` in it's entirety to `cloneTemp.txt`. Yet, it is not.

Comment: You are not showing enough code to figure this out. `cloneTemp` creates and opens a file called `cloneTemp.txt` ... and then doesn't use it for anything. It then copies the file in `newFileLocation` to `cloneTemp.txt`. So you've overwritten the file you just created and even if you wrote to `cloneFile` it wouldn't go into the now-current 'cloneTemp.txt'. `gridEnable` then copies "cloneTemp.txt" back into whatever that newFileLocation is, but doesn't append any lines to it. Can you make this a working example to reduce confusion?

Comment: @tdelaney I've edited the post, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @tdelaney I've ran it and it copies over everything from `newFileLocation`  over to `cloneTemp.txt` but lines are missing.  `Main.py` runs these functions after `newFileLocation` has been generated.

Comment: `copyfile` doesn't append to the file, it replaces it. Are the missing lines the ones you wrote to `cloneTemp.txt` before the `copyfile`?

Comment: @MarkRansom no the missing lines are from the `copyfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still confused about what you want but here is a strawman answer. This code will take a file in `newFileLocation` and will add data to the front and back of the file.

```
with open('cloneTemp.txt', 'w') as tmp:
    tmp.write(x)
    with open(newFileLocation) as newfile:
        shutil.copyfileobj(newfile, tmp)
    tmp.write(y)
os.rename('cloneTemp.txt', newFileLocation)
```

So, lets test

```
import shutil
import os

# file to test
newFileLocation = 'testfile.txt'
open(newFileLocation, 'w').write('this\nis\na\ntest\n')
print('before:')
print(open(newFileLocation).read())

with open('cloneTemp.txt', 'w') as tmp:
    tmp.write('header\n')
    with open(newFileLocation) as newfile:
        shutil.copyfileobj(newfile, tmp)
    tmp.write('footer\n')
os.rename('cloneTemp.txt', newFileLocation)
print('after:')
print(open(newFileLocation).read())
```

Produces

```
before:
this
is
a
test

after:
header
this
is
a
test
footer
```

Comment: Since I can't prepend to the beginning of the `newFileLocation`, I am creating a temporary file of `newFileLocation` called `cloneTemp.txt` to copy over the data **only after** I've added the lines into the empty `cloneTemp.txt` that I require. After the lines are added, `shutil.copyfile()` should copy `newFileLocation` in it's entirety to `cloneTemp.txt`. Yet, it is not.

Comment: Your continued refusal to write a runnable example (what the heck is `newfile`?) or tell us which lines are missing makes this harder. After `shutil.copyfile(newFileLocation, 'cloneTemp.txt')` runs, those two files will be identical. But you are holding a different pointer for the file `cloneFile = open('cloneTemp.txt', 'w+')`. If you write to that file object, it will overwrite the `newFileLocation` stuff you just wrote. I posted an example of how to do it correctly. Does it meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Most file I/O is buffered. That means when you write information to the file, some of it doesn't hit the disk immediately; it stays in buffers within the program until enough has been collected to be worth writing out.

To be safe, you should close the file before you copy it:

```
newFile.close()
```

Comment: You are absolutely right that OP will loose data if `newfile` isn't flushed or closed. But assuming `newfile` is the `newFileLocation` file, his next step is to `copyfile` over it, so any data written will be lost anyway.

Comment: @tdelaney You are correct, my mistake in not properly clarifying.